# I am scraping Html table they show me the error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select''

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, request

I am scraping Html table they show me the error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select' try to solve it

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
    }
    r = requests.get("https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table',attrs={'style':"border"})
    
    
    
    all_data = []
    for row in table.select("tr:has(td)"):
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
        all_data.append(tds)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=header)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Make sure that the object you're calling `select` on is not `None`. Probably it can't find that table given the criteria you specified.

Comment: Is any method to solve it

Comment: You can go to that url in a browser, open developer tools and look at the document structure, and then write the `.find` query accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that website you are trying to scrape blocks the requests sent by `requests` library. To deal with the issue, I used `Selenium` library which automates the website browsing. The code below collects the titles given in the table.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
    
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"}
    
all_data = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select("option")]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Titles"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
                                           Titles
0                   Agree Realty Corporation (ADC)
1          American Campus Communities, Inc. (ACC)
2                Antero Midstream Corporation (AM)
3                Antero Resources Corporation (AR)
4                               Apache Corp. (APA)
..                                             ...
126                         W. P. Carey Inc. (WPC)
127  Washington Real Estate Investment Trust (WRE)
128                          Welltower Inc. (WELL)
129           Western Midstream Partners, LP (WES)
130            Whiting Petroleum Corporation (WLL)
```

If you have not used `Selenium` before, do not forget to install `chromedriver.exe` and add it to the PATH environment variable. You can also give the location of the driver to the constructor manually.

**Updated code to extract extra information**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
    
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action")

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"}

for title in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('option'):
    title.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("iframe")[1])
    table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table table")
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "lxml")
    all_data = []
    ratings = {"BUY":[], "HOLD":[], "SELL":[]}
    lists_ = []
    for row in soup.select("tr")[-4:-1]:
        info_list = row.select("td")
        count = info_list[1].text
        percent = info_list[2].text
        
        IBServ_count = info_list[4].text
        IBServ_percent = info_list[5].text
        
        lists_.append([count, percent, IBServ_count, IBServ_percent])
        
    ratings["BUY"] = lists_[0]
    ratings["HOLD"] = lists_[1]
    ratings["SELL"] = lists_[2]
    
    print(ratings)
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: but I have to scrape these link (`https://capitalonebank2.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action')

Comment: you do it wonderful job to scrape these link but my target to scrape the link that I have shared

Comment: if you open the link then select it `Agree Realty Corporation (ADC)` then scrape these

Comment: yes I want to scrape these

Comment: I want to scrape `Rating` ,`Count`,`percent`

Comment: Do you have to run it ?? I run these code they show me error

Comment: Can you share the error? I've run it and it worked.

Comment: they show these error `raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: Could you please download ```chromedriver.exe``` from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and add its location to the PATH? You can't run ```Selenium``` without a driver.

Comment: ok I download the driver and try to run code

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for disturbance if you provide these in `data frame`

Comment: can you help  in these matter

Comment: I answered to your question about dataframe, please check that out.

Comment: where I cannot see that answer

Comment: I answered the question named as "I want the data in 'data frame' the code is working perfectly". It's one of your last questions.